# How do I make the same code work for multiple dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to python and I making a quiz which asks the user if they would like to play on easy, medium, or hard then the code displays the questions depending on what difficulty the user has chosen. I have all the questions and answers in dictionaries (1 dictionary for each difficulty such as a dict for easy questions and answers and a dict for hard questions and answers etc) and I have this part of the code which checks if the users answer is right or wrong. The problem is that the part of the code which checks if the answer is right or wrong can only use one dictionary at a time. The other problem is that I don't know how to make it that if the user picks easy then the code prints out the easy questions from the easy dict.The part `if answer.lower() == Question_list_easy[ques]:` only allows 1 dict which is why I think the code only allows one dict at a time.  I have tried `if chooses == "easy": print (Question_list_easy)` but it doesn't work. Please help me.

```
import random

quiz_difficulty = input("Would you like to play on easy, medium, or hard\n").lower()
if quiz_difficulty == "easy":
  print (Question_list_easy)
   
if quiz_difficulty == "medium":
   print (Question_list_medium)

if quiz_difficulty == "hard":
   print (Question_list_hard)


Question_list_easy = {
   "How many days are there in a year?":"365",
   "How many hours are there in a day?":"24", 
   "How many days are there in a week?":"7"
   } 

Question_list_medium = {
   "How many weeks are there in a year?":"52",
   "How many years are there in a decade?":"10", 
   "How many days are there in a fortnight?":"14"
   } 

Question_list_hard = {
   "How many years are there in a millennium?":"1000",
   "How many days are there in 2 years?":"730", 
   "How many years are there in a half a century?":"50"
   } 
  


#The part which asks the questions and verifies if the answer the user does is coreect or incorrect. It also randomizes the questions
question = list (Question_list_easy.keys())
#input answer here 
while True:
    if not question:
        break
    ques = random.choice(question)
    print(ques)
    while True:
        answer = input('Answer ' )
        # if correct, moves onto next question
        if answer.lower() == Question_list_easy[ques]:
            print("Correct Answer")
            break
        else:
            #if wrong, Asks the same question again
            print("Wrong Answer, try again")
    question.remove(ques)
```

Comment: Not related to the question but a millennium is 1000 years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notwithstanding the fact that some of the answers to the questions are wrong, here's a way to achieve your objective with less code. The key feature here is the use of a dictionary where the key/value pairs are the difficulty level mapped to the appropriate dictionary of questions. This obviates the need for if/then/else when choosing the difficulty level and is thus more extensible should you ever want to add more levels of difficulty:-

```
Question_list_easy = {
    "How many days are there in a year?": "365",
    "How many hours are there in a day?": "24",
    "How many days are there in a week?": "7"
}

Question_list_medium = {
    "How many weeks are there in a year?": "52",
    "How many years are there in a decade?": "10",
    "How many days are there in a fortnight?": "14"
}

Question_list_hard = {
    "How many years are there in a millennium?": "365",
    "How many days are there in 2 years?": "730",
    "How many days are there in a half a century?": "50"
}

qmap = {'easy': Question_list_easy,
        'medium': Question_list_medium,
        'hard': Question_list_hard}

questions = None

while questions is None:
    inp = input('Would you like to play easy, medium, or hard? ')
    questions = qmap.get(inp)

while len(questions) > 0:
    _i = random.randint(0, len(questions) - 1)
    _key = list(questions)[_i]
    inp = input(_key+' ')
    if inp == questions[_key]:
        print('Correct')
        questions.pop(_key)
    else:
        print('Incorrect. Try again')
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks pretty close, but I think the part you're missing is where you could say:

```
if quiz_difficulty == "easy":
   question_list = Question_list_easy
if quiz_difficulty == "medium":
   question_list = Question_list_medium
if quiz_difficulty == "hard":
   question_list = Question_list_hard
```

Then, in your section where you ask the question, you would just use `question_list` instead of specifically referencing `Question_list_easy`.

Comment: you're a genius! I really can't thank you enough

Answer (score 1):

Put the part which asks the questions in a function, and pass the appropriate dict into the function, like this:

```
def ask_the_questions(q_dict):
    #The part which asks the questions ons
    question = list (q_dict.keys())
    ... etc ...
```

Then call the function with the appropriate dict, for example:

```
ask_the_question(Question_list_easy)
```

Answer (score 1):

**I have changed your code as follow:**

```
question = ''
question_set = ''
if quiz_difficulty == "easy":
  question = list (Question_list_easy.keys())
  question_set = Question_list_easy
   
if quiz_difficulty == "medium":
   question = list (Question_list_medium.keys())
   question_set = Question_list_medium

if quiz_difficulty == "hard":
   question = list (Question_list_hard.keys())
   question_set = Question_list_hard

while True:
    if not question or not question_set:
        break
    ques = random.choice(question)
    print(ques)
    while True:
        answer = input('Answer ' )
        # if correct, moves onto next question
        if answer.lower() == question_set[ques]:
            print("Correct Answer")
            break
        else:
            #if wrong, Asks the same question again
            print("Wrong Answer, try again")
    question.remove(ques)
```